# FormFunction output not working

Tags: cloud-deploy, form-building

Following is my form function:

```
addressForm = FormFunction[{
   "StreetAddress" -> "String",
   "City" -> "String",
   "State" -> "String",
   "ZIPCode" -> "Number"
   }, addressCallback[#StreetAddress, #City, #State, #ZIPCode] &]
```

and the function that applies to the input:

```
addressCallback[StreetAddress_, City_, State_, ZIPCode_] :=

 Module[
   {ste = StringTrim[ToString[StreetAddress]], 
    ctt = StringTrim[ToString[City]], 
    stt = StringTrim[ToString[State]], 
    zip = StringTrim[ToString[ZIPCode]]},
   Return[ste <> 
     If[StringDrop[ste, StringLength[ste] - 1] == ",", "", ","] <> 
     " " <> ctt <> ", " <> stt <> "-" <> zip]
   ]
```

I see some output in the message console (error, which is weird) and when I deploy it online with

```
CloudDeploy[addressForm, Permissions -> "Public"]
```

there is no output after form submission, just a blank page. Kindly help me.

Comment: Your code seems to work as intended (?) locally. For instance, I get the following output after running your code and putting in some made-up values: [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9h2er.png) (the result does appear in the main notebook, not in the message console). I didn't deploy it, so I don't know about that part.

Comment: Works well on cloud too. What's your `$CloudCreditsAvailable`?